# import python modules at runtime from a specific path

Tags: python-2.7, python-import

I am trying to import the python file from the specific path with reference to some examples mentioned on SO. I am getting the *ImportError: Import by filename is not supported. *

**dynamic.py**

```
    import importlib
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        module = importlib.import_module("/home/ilx1/Desktop/frontend/Demo")
        MyClass = module.Demo()
        MyClass.sample_function()
```

**Demo.py**

```
class Demo():
    def sample_function(self):
        print "import success"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d=Demo()
    d.sample_function()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `imp` module on python 2.7

```
import imp



demo = imp.load_source('demo', '/home/ilx1/Desktop/frontend/Demo.py')
d = demo.Demo()
d.sample_function() # Prints >> import success
```